# JFrame Form add from JTextField to JList

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jlist

I'm trying to make a contact field where you can type in a first name and a last name in two separate text fields and click the "Add" button I created to send it to the list, but I'm unsure of how to do this exactly, being new to jFrame. I was using something in a tutorial that was similar to this using floats (which is shown below), only because I wasn't sure how to use the "String" variation, however this only seems to work when the "setText" command is set on another text field and won't work on a jList.

```
float num1, num2, result;
num1 = Float.parseFloat(textFieldFirstName.getText());
num2 = Float.parseFloat(textFieldLastName.getText());
result = num1+num2;
listFieldContact.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Are there any ideas or even good resources out there for jFrame? I've looked in a lot of places but they never quite seem to have exactly the information I need.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the text to `float`?

Comment: Why did you delete the question that I just answered? [Running an applet by extending JApplet and as a standalone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647603/running-an-applet-by-extending-japplet-and-as-a-standalone-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this only seems to work when the "setText" command is set on another text field and won't work on a jList.

A JList doesn't have a setText(...) method. You need to update the `ListModel`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example that does almost exactly what you want.

The example uses a single text field by you should easily be able to get it to work with two text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String fname = textFieldFirstName.getText();
String lname = textFieldLastName.getText();
listFieldContact = fname + " " + lname;
```

You don't need float conversion, as MadProgrammer pointed out.  You do need a space between first and last name.  Maybe you want `lname + ", " + fname` in other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make the values available in the JList it is not necessary to use Float for string operation. We can do it like this :

```
Vector<String> nameVector = new Vector<>();
JList<String> nameList = new JList<>();

public void addText() {
    nameVector.add(firstNameTF.getText()+lastNameTF.getText());
    nameList.setListData(nameVector);
}
```

I think this piece of code will help you to solve your query.